# Clicking inside a sliding drawer

Tags: android, slidingdrawer

I have a sliding drawer implemented. But the problem is this:

I have a list view on the main screen with a drawer handle seen in the bottom
If I click on the list view - I have programmed it to open another activity.

When I open the sliding drawer it pops open beautifully.
But when I click inside the sliding drawers contents, It responds as if I have clicked the list view in the previous screen!

Any help as to how to avoid this might be of great help!
Thanks in advance.

Comment: please post the code... I need it urgently.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved this. I needed the sliding drawer to display a menu. Filled up the drawers content with the menu options and tadaa! problem solved. I think this problem arose due to the face that even though the sliding drawer seems like a separate "view" it actually is in the same view.